# NSMutableArray addOject rewrites data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I know there are a lot of questions based on the same topic. But none seem to be solving my problem.

I have a `NSMutableArray` `_buttonArray` and a `NSMutableDictionary` `_singleBtn`.

When I press a button, I add the dictionary to the array. But the array is getting overwritten.

```
[_singleBtn setObject:scanBarCodeButton.titleLabel.text forKey:@"text"];
[_singleBtn setObject:NSStringFromCGRect(scanBarCodeButton.frame) forKey:@"frame"];
[_buttonArray addObject:_singleBtn];
```

In the first iteration, I get the following:

```
{
    frame = "{{20, 40}, {50, 40}}";
    text = abc;
}
```

Now if I add the text "xyz", it gives me:

```
{
    frame = "{{20, 90}, {80, 40}}";
    text = xyz;
},
    {
    frame = "{{20, 90}, {80, 40}}";
    text = xyz;
}
```

I've done the allocation of both the array and the dictionary in my `viewDidLoad`

Comment: try [_buttonArray addObject:[_singleBtn copy]];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an overwrite of a previously added object - the reason you see this is that you have added a reference to the same object two times. Your `NSMutableArray` looks like this:

```
[_singleBtn, _singleBtn]
```

`NSMutableArray` does not make copies of objects that you insert, so you need to take care of making new objects before inserting them.

One way of making a copy is passing `_singleBtn` to a method that copies it into a new dictionary, like this:

```
[_buttonArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:_singleBtn]];
```